# How to retrieve data on the basis of parent field

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two table named `user` and `customer`.

The relation is `user.id = customer.user_id`.

Now I want to select from `customer` model on the basis of Parent model (`user`), like this `select c.* from customer as c inner join user as u ON c.user_id = u.id WHERE u.status = '1'`

Now how to do that with laravel eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$customers = Customer::whereHas('user', function($q) {
    $q->where('status', 1);
})->get();
```

Also make sure you have `user` method declared in your `Customer` Model:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('user','user_id','id');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You solved my many question. I am a big fan you. Again thank you.